# C# and eksblowfish

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, blowfish

Anyone know where I can find a C# implementation of eksblowfish crypt?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the Blowfish algorithm?

Comment: No, he means [eksblowfish](http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node4.html) (= Expensive Key Schedule Blowfish) as used in Unix crypt. The link JPReddy's given him is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one available on codeplex. [Check this](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/).